# postgres array_eq & user-created equality

Tags: postgresql

While waiting for 9.4, I have created an equality operator for json:

```
select '"1"'::json = '"1"'::json
```

returns true.

However, when I try:

```
select array_eq('{"1"}'::json[],'{"1"}'::json[]);
```

I get:

```
ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json
SQL state: 42883
```

What is going on here? Does array_eq not recognize user-defined equality? Or is there something else I have missed? Should I define my own `array_eq(anyarray, anyarray)`?

**UPDATE**

In fact, even after I provide my own equality for `json[]`, I can't use a `select distinct` including
results that contain `json[]` which was the purpose of this. Any suggested workarounds?

**UPDATE (suggestion by Craig)** Operators:

```
drop operator if exists =(json, json) cascade;

create operator = (
    procedure = json_eq,
    leftarg = json,
    rightarg = json,
    commutator = =,
    restrict = eqsel,
    join = eqjoinsel
);
drop operator if exists =(json[], json[]) cascade;
create or replace function array_eq2( a json[], b json[] ) returns boolean
    language sql as
$$
    select array_ndims(a) = array_ndims(b) 
        and (select bool_and(array_length(a,i) = array_length(b,i))
            from generate_series(1,array_ndims(a)) _(i))
        and (select bool_and(a[i] = b[i]) 
            from generate_series(1,array_length(a,1)) _(i));
$$;
create operator = (
    procedure = array_eq2,
    leftarg = json[],
    rightarg = json[],
    commutator = =,
    restrict = eqsel,
    join = eqjoinsel
);
```

Comment: Y'know what'd be helpful? If you posted the SQL for your user-defined equality operator ;-)

Comment: Craig -- there you go ... though given the error is "could not identify..." it would seem that the specifics are immaterial? I suspect that built in "distinct" and "array_eq" may not be checking for user defined operators?